# Error while passing Multiple Values in a single input parameter in SAP HANA calculation View (sps12)

Tags: hana

​I've written a table function for passing multiple values in a single input parameter. And I'm consuming the same in the CV. It's working perfectly fine.
But the problem arises when I want to see the data without any condition. i.e. It throws an error when I pass '*' as a input.
What should be done in this case where I want to see all the data(sometimes) and with filters sometimes.
I'm trying to handle the same. But it gives the below error. When I fetch raw data from the calculation View.

**Error:** 
SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error: [2620] "HADMIN"."RA.Test.Prathamesh::PH_MULTIPLE_INPUT": line 22 col 1 (at pos 589): [130] (range 2) InternalFatal exception: table config for index HADMIN:_SYS_SS_CE_60839900_vers1_lang6_type2__2_CS_1_3_RET is not valid

**CODE:**

```
FUNCTION "HADMIN"."RA.Test.Prathamesh::PH_MULTIPLE_INPUT" (IN IP_FORMAT_CD NVARCHAR(3)) 
    RETURNS TABLE (STORE_NO NVARCHAR(10), FORMAT_CD NVARCHAR(3), SALE_QTY DECIMAL(10,3))
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER AS
BEGIN
BEGIN

vfact = select A.STORE_NO,A.FORMAT_CD,SALE_QTY 
        from HADMIN.S_SITE_MASTER A 
        INNER JOIN HADMIN.A_ITT_ITEM_SALES B
        ON A.STORE_NO = B.STORE_NO
        WHERE 
        B.TRANS_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-1) AND CURRENT_DATE;


IF ( :IP_FORMAT_CD = '*' )
THEN

var_out = CE_PROJECTION(:vfact,
["STORE_NO","FORMAT_CD","SALE_QTY"],
'IN("FORMAT_CD",$$IP_FORMAT_CD$$)');    

ELSE

var_out =  CE_PROJECTION(:vfact,
["STORE_NO","FORMAT_CD","SALE_QTY"],
'IN("FORMAT_CD",$$IP_FORMAT_CD$$)'); 

END IF; 
END;

RETURN 

SELECT * FROM :var_out; 

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use the deprecated `CE_`-functions!
For the dynamic filtering use the `APPLY_FILTER()` function.
The function is well documented and I even gave several examples here on SO, so I won’t repeat that now.

Comment: If I use APPLY_FILTER in as Table Function. Will I be able to consume the same table function in the calculation view ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. Why wouldn't you?